# How to set folders permissions in linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, edit

I am supposed to give write/edit permission to my directory in /var/lib/mysql/dbname via Linux.

I am unaware of backend UI and i know i just enetered the text "sudu so" @ centos machine which displays :
[root@ip-10-0-0-61 centos]#

Can anyone tell how to proceed further as I have always been using WinScp which restricts me to write database files due to present set permissions.

Any user interface file manager that could do this would be really helpful too.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to look at, setting permissions, and ownership.

To do this for an entire directory (be careful with this)

```
chmod -R {permissions} {directory}
```

If you're unsure what permissions to use [check this guide](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)

To set ownership, use

```
chown {user:group} {directory} -R
```

Again be careful with these settings. It's not often you'll want an entire directory full of files to all have the same permissions, and you could be opening yourself up to risks if you do so. Always be explicit and give each file the minimum permissions needed to get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

You can change files/folders permission with the `chmod` command. There's a man page [here](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html). The full command line to type depends on which permission you exactly need. A basic usage of the command is

```
chmod [ugoa][+-=][rwx] file
```

Where

- `[ugoa]` allow you to choose whose permission you want to modify: the owner of the file (`u`), users member of the group of the file (`g`), any other users (`o`) and all users (`a`)
- `[+-=]` allow you to tell the command if you want to add (`+`) the selected permissions, remove them (`-`) or set them as the only permissions of the file(`=`).
- `[rwx]` allow you to choose the permission : read (`r`), write (`w`) or execute (`x`). There exist other type of permissions explained in the man.

To change the permission of a folder recursively, you can add the option `-R` to the command.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple just execute the command
`chmod 777 -R ./` 
This will do the trick for you.